# Show that for any $A \in \sigma(\vartheta)$, then $A \in \sigma(\xi_{k})$ where $\xi_{k}$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\vartheta$ be a collection of subsets of the set $X$. Show that for each $A$ in $\sigma(\vartheta)$ there is a countable subfamily $\xi_{0}$ of $\vartheta$ such that $A \in \sigma(\xi_{0})$.

Hint given in the exercise:

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the union of $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(\xi)$, where $\xi$ ranges over the countable subfamilies of $\vartheta$, and show that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that satisfies $\vartheta \subset \mathcal{A} \subset \sigma(\vartheta)$.

So the first thing we need to show is that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

$\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$, since the empty set belongs to each $\sigma$-algebra in the union of $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{A}$.

If $A\in \mathcal{A}$, then $A \in \sigma(\xi_{k})$ for some countable subfamily $\xi_{k}$ of $\vartheta$, hence, $A^{C} \in \sigma(\xi_{k})$ and therefore also $A^{c} \in \mathcal{A}$.

Let $(A_{i})$ be a sequence of sets in $\mathcal{A}$, then there exists to each $A_{i}$ a $\sigma$-algebra $\xi_{i}$ s.t. $A_{i} \in \sigma(\xi_{i})$. Then define $\hat{\xi}$ as $\cup_{i} \xi_{i}$. This is a countable union and $\xi_{i} \subset \hat{\xi}$  $\forall i$. Hence, $\sigma(\xi_{i}) \subset \sigma(\hat{\xi})$, and $\cup_{i} A_{i}$ $\in \sigma(\hat{\xi}) \subset \mathcal{A}$. Hence, $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under countable unions.

If this last step is valid, we have shown that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

The next step to show is that

$\vartheta \subset \mathcal{A} \subset \sigma(\vartheta)$.

Let $B \in \vartheta$, then $\{B\}$ is a countable subfamily of $\vartheta$ and then belongs to $\sigma(\{B\})$ and therefore $B \in \mathcal{A}$.

Now let $B\in \mathcal{A}$, then $B \in \sigma(\xi_{k})$ for some countable subset $\xi_{k}$ of $\vartheta$, and since $\xi_{k} \subset \vartheta$ then $\sigma(\xi_{k}) \subset \sigma(\vartheta)$ so then $B \in \sigma(\vartheta)$.

This gives

$\vartheta \subset \mathcal{A} \subset \sigma(\vartheta)$, and since $\sigma(\vartheta)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containg $\vartheta$, $\sigma(\vartheta) \subset \mathcal{A}$.

We can now conclude that for any set $A\in \sigma(\vartheta)$, there exists a countable subfamily $\xi_{k}$ of $\vartheta$ such that $A\in\sigma(\xi_{k})$.

Does this hold all the way or are some steps not true or unclear?

Answer (score 1):

- »$\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$« does not show anything.
- $\xi_k \in \xi$ is not true/unclear, since $\xi$ is not defined. I think you mean that $\xi_k$ is some countable subfamily of $\theta$. »$\xi$ ranges over« does not mean »$\xi$ consists of«.
- In showing that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under taking countable unions, you have to write that you want $A_i \in \mathcal{A}$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Also your final argument for that point is unclear. First of all $\bigcup_i A_i$ cannot be a subset of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Ok, so what does range over mean? 

Yes, $A_{i}$ shall belong to $\mathcal{A}$ for all $i$, and $\mathcal{A}$ is the union of all $\sigma$-algebras of countable subfamilies of $\vartheta$, so each $A_{i}$ must lie in one of the $\sigma$-algebras. Why does that not make $\cup_{i} A_{i} $ a subset of $\mathcal{A}$? The union of the sigma-algebras must be a bigger set than the union of single elements of the sigma-algebras? Thanks in advance!

Comment: And the empty set belongs to each sigma-algebra and then also the union of sigma-algebras.

Comment: »Range over« means to take the union over the set of all such subfamilies. You can give this set a name, but it it would be confusing to call it $\xi$, since in the statement a generic element of that set is called $\xi$. - The sets of $\mathcal{A}$ are $\sigma$-algebras, while the $A_i$ are elements of some of those $\sigma$-algebras, so the union of the $A_i$ is typically not a $\sigma$-algebra. Maybe what you are thinking of is $\bigcup_i A_i \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for claryfing. But $\cup_{i} A_{i}$ need not to be a $\sigma$-algebra, all we need is that $\cup_{i}A_{i} \in \mathcal{A}$, so that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. And $\mathcal{A}$ is a union of $\sigma$-algebras. Maybe you can show how you would do it? Maybe I am mixing $\cup_{i} A_{i} \in \mathcal{A}$ with $\cup_{i} A_{i} \subset \mathcal{A}$?

Comment: Sorry, my comment is wrong: $\mathcal{A}$ consists of subsets of $X$, while $\bigcup_i A_i$ is a subset of $X$, so it will not be a subset of a set of subsets of $X$, but it is an element of $\mathcal{A}$, as you say. But you still have to write down why it is an element of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: I changed in my proof now. Hope it is better now :).

Comment: Now the part about the closedness under countable unions is correct :)